# AchartEngine background transparent

Tags: android

I have a problem with achartengine 1.0. I set the background transparent, `setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));` but the plot line goes off the chart and it looks ugly. How do I fix it?
And how do the x-axis oisujące data were shown as one (1,2,3,4,5 ...) and not, as now (1, 1.5, 2, 2,5 ....)? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3MbZ.png

Answer (score 0):

To get the X-axis labels to be whole numbers try this:

```
for(int m=0;m<maximum_possible_value;m++){
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(m, Integer.toString(m));
}
mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);
```

This will set all the X axis labels to be whole number values. maximum_possible_value is the maximum possible value in the x axis.